# Maven: Prevent upload of default-jar - only upload jar-with-dependencies

Tags: deployment, maven, jar

I'm evaluating Maven 3 at work. For several example projects I have to deploy them to a server (no repository), but that's not the problem.

In my current example-project I'm trying to upload only the "jar-with-dependencies". 
and exactly that's my problem.

It all works fine, except that the main-artifact AND the jar-with-dependencies (created by the assembly-plugin) are uploaded.

How do I prevent Maven or rather the deploy-phase from uploading the main-jar and only upload a given or specified file (in this case, the assembly-file "jar-with-dependencies")?

Referring to the question *[Only create executable jar-with-dependencies in Maven](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5016467)*, I can't just alter the packaging-setting to pom, because it will also prevent the assembly-plugin from adding my classes to the JAR file. It only creates a JAR file with the files of the dependencies.

I hope I'm clear about my problem, and you can help me ;)

Comment: If you are trying to upload only "jar-with-dependencies" it sounds like you didn't understand the concept of Maven. Cause a build will result in an artifact which is a jar (or war, ear etc.) and not with it's dependencies which is not achievable with the Maven-assembly-plugin. The question is what you like to achieve?

Comment: Well, my goal is to get to know how I can specify which file Maven should deploy and which not.
I'm familiar with the concept of Maven and the jar-with-dependencies was just a result of learning how to use Maven and common plugins. With the basis of these 2 jars I wanted to learn how to deploy specific files. To prevent misunderstandings you can call them first-jar and second-jar within the same project. I hope you understand what I'm trying to say ^^

Answer (score 0):

if you just looking how to add a file to be deployed you can take a look here:

http://mojo.codehaus.org/build-helper-maven-plugin/attach-artifact-mojo.html

May be this helps. If not express your needs more in detail.

Comment: It helps a bit, but only for future projects ;)
I want to configure the deploy-plugin (or something else, if there is sth. else) to upload a jar that i specify - overwriting the standard configuration of the plugin. I want to tell maven "upload this jar, and not this one" ... something like that.
Right now, I don't know how to be more specific ^^ and I hope you understand my thoughts

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be no way to configure the deploy plugin to filter out some of the artifacts from a project and selectively deploy the others. Faced with a similar problem, we solved this with the [ease-maven-plugin](https://github.com/neo4j/ease-maven-plugin). It fit well into our release process but might not be the right choice for everyone as it mandates a two-step approach. During the build you would make a list of all artifacts and filter out those that you want deployed. In a second step, you then run `mvn deploy` on a separate project (or separate profile) in which the list of artifacts is attached to the project as the only artifacts which then get deployed. See the examples in the source code of the ease maven plugin to better understand how it works.

The original version is not able to filter out specific artifacts of a project. I have [forked](https://github.com/fzs/ease-maven-plugin) the project and added patches that add this.