# How to create single jar with dependencies in maven

Tags: java, maven, jar, maven-3

I am trying to create single fat jar using maven assembly plugin but somehow after running `maven clean install` it give 2 jars, one is client-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar and other one is client-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar.

I am only interested to create a jar with dependencies so dont know why the other jar is also creating by this assemble plugin.
Can someone tell me how to eliminate this jar Or should i use some other maven command rather than clean install ?

```
<build>
        <finalName>${project.artifactId}-${project.version}</finalName>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>${basedir}/src/main/resources</directory>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>*.properties</exclude>
                </excludes>
            </resource>
        </resources>

        <plugins>

            <!-- download source code in Eclipse, best practice -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.9</version>
                <configuration>
                    <downloadSources>true</downloadSources>
                    <downloadJavadocs>false</downloadJavadocs>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <!-- Set a compiler level -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${jdk.version}</source>
                    <target>${jdk.version}</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <!-- Maven Assembly Plugin -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <!-- get all project dependencies -->
                    <descriptorRefs>
                        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                    </descriptorRefs>
                    -->
                    <!-- MainClass in mainfest make a executable jar -->
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <mainClass>com.app.MainApp</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>

                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>make-assembly</id>
                        <!-- bind to the packaging phase -->
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>copy-resources</id>
                        <phase>install</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy-resources</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <!-- overwrite! -->
                            <overwrite>true</overwrite>
                            <outputDirectory>${project.basedir}/target</outputDirectory>
                            <resources>

                                <resource>
                                    <directory>${project.basedir}/</directory>
                                    <includes>
                                        <include>*.properties</include>
                                    </includes>
                                </resource>

                            </resources>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>

                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

Comment: Can you just ignore the other JAR?

Comment: lol yes off course but just curious why the other jar comes there which have no dependencies and useless to run as well

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Only create executable jar-with-dependencies in Maven](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5016467/only-create-executable-jar-with-dependencies-in-maven)

Comment: Why are you excluding the resources in the resources area but on the other hand using maven-resources-plugin to copy the resources from the {basedir} into target folder? Why not putting the resource files into the src/main/resources folder and follow the conventions and afterwards you can simply remove the configuration for resources and the part for the maven-resources-plugin...

Comment: Well in project i have a configuration property file which i dont want to include in a final jar but just want to place it outside the final jar when build finish. so that excluding and then copying resources

Comment: If those properties do not belong into the jar just remove them...sounds wrong...